# after deploy the .NET 6 web api in iis I can access the normal array data. but I can't access the data which are store in database

Tags: c#, database, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I create a web API using .NET 6 and using mysql then I create a controller and I store the data in database using entity framework.and I deploy my solution in IIS after deploy I can't access api which are store databas. I can access local data which are store in normal array.

Appsetting.Json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ContactsApiConnectionString": "Server=STL-TECH-IT;Encrypt=False;Database=ContactsDb;User Id = sa; Persist Security Info=true; Password=password;Trusted_Connection= true ; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; "
  }
}
```

after deploy in IIS i can access the default weatherforcast data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LekHA.png)

but if i want to access my data which are store in database it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knrQZ.png)

I try to access the api which are store in my database.

Comment: If something crashes then you need to check your logs to see what happened. What I can see directly is that your your connectionstring is wrong. The password isn't set with `pdf=` but `Password=`. It might be that simple, but you need to check the logs.

Comment: Thank you after checking event log I solved it.